# How to get the name of drawable through resource id?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I am trying to make the bitmap and for this I need the drawable name such as:

```
overlayScaledBitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.monkey);
```

This is working fine But my problem is that I can not do this same thing when a user selects a picture from a list because I have done this statically. As you can see I have wrote R.drawable.monkey. So its means every time it is going to create bitmap with monkey image.

But it is not the case, the user selects image which gets fixed into the image view. Now I want to get the `ImageView` as drawable. If it is possible then it could be dynamically and would be easy to handle. Any idea How I can get drawable of `ImageView` to use in bitmap scaling? please help

Comment: wait you want the name of the resources given its id or what ?

Comment: in BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.monkey); i need id

Comment: so you want to retrieve the id of a resource given its name?

Comment: no I want the id of a picture which is set by the user in the imageview by clicking on the list of pictures. I want to create bitmap of same picture which is clicked by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an enum object containing all refs to the bitmaps and an id.

But another way is using getTag() and setTag() on the resources to identify by.